# haskell instance unresolved overloading

Tags: haskell

I have a class Binaer with the method a_zu_binaer:

```
> class Binaer a where
>   a_zu_binaer :: a -> String
```

And an instance:

```
> instance Binaer Integer where
>   a_zu_binaer b = "needs to be converted"
```

When I call for example

```
a_zu_binaer 3
```

I get the error `Unresolved Overloading`

What is the reason for this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happen of `a_zu_binaer (3::Integer)` ? It seems you have more than one instance of `class Binaer`.

Comment: Haskell does not know if that `3` is an integer or any other numeric type. After all, one could later on add instances for `Binaer Int`, `Binaer Float`, etc. These can even be declared in another file.

Comment: @assembly.jc It does not matter if you have more instances right now or not. Haskell works under an "open world" assumption, where instances might always be added (even in other source files).

Comment: calling it over a_zu_binaer (3::Integer) solves my problem. Thank you1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enter a multi line definition into ghci, you have to surround it with `:{` and `:}`.

In Your case, the first line declares a class without methods, the second a signature to a unrelated funktion and so on.

I's in general a good idea to store your definitions in a file and use ghci only to try them out.